# Include LeakCanary on release builds

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I would like to inspect memory leaks happening on the wide and get them logged on Crashlytics or any other crash reporting tool

I am using LeakCanary as a tool in the debug build but I would also like to have a minimal version of it that just sends the logs of a suspect leak, without effecting my Android application performance